# Launch multiple applications and move them to separated spaces with one click

Tags: spaces

Every time I'm starting using my Mac I'm opening app X, Y and Z and then moving them to separated spaces. Is there any easy way to do this automatically with one click? For eg. launch X, Y and Z, move X to Desktop 1, move Y to Desktop 2, move Z to Desktop 3 and minimize it.

Comment: Is it on startup that you need this only? Or also at other times?  If only on startup no need for a click can do it automatically.

Comment: Mostly on startup but it will be great to have control on this, I don't always want to start some heavy apps when I'm not planning to use them. I know that MacOS has ability to start some apps on startup and this can be set in preferences.

Comment: You can lock an application to [always be assigned to a specific space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191966). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Nic Thanks, it is helpful because I don't know this feature but it still doesn't answer my question I think. I can connect this with something that will open multiple apps with one click and maybe it can do the job. But I don't know any app/feature which has ability to open multiple apps with single command / click.